# How to use String operation like split and compare in Drools condition

Tags: drools, rule-engine

I have an Object with string member attribute which can have values like `23,4`.
Now I need to split the `String` in when block in drools rule like

`str.split[','][0] == 23`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use proper Java syntax, like

```
str.split(",")[0].equals("23")
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. str.split(",")[0] == 1 works fine. What if 'str' is not String, it is of type Object? How can we cast that object to String and do that operation? eg. ((String)str).split(",")[0] == 1. This throws error in my system.

Comment: Please ignore above comment. That one works fine. Thanks Laune.